# how to update a user in mongoDB using findOneAndUpdate? Throwing internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, axios

Okay so I am currently writing an API that when called, should update the current user in mongoDB using data passed in the request.

However, when I call findOneAndUpdate(), I get a 500 internal server error. (i will show a couple of the ways I've attempted to make it work below)

When I call findOne(), it finds and returns the correct user without issue. However then I ran into the issue of not being able to update the user, I tried user.name = request.body.name; followed by user.save(); but that did not work. So I decided to try findOneAndUpdate again.

here are a couple of ways I've tried so far

```
app.post("/account/edit", auth, (request, response) => {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({email: request.user.userEmail}, {name: request.body.name, email: request.body.email})
        .then((user) => {
            response.send(user)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.status(404).send({
                message: "User not found",
                error,
            });
        })
    }
)
```

or originally I had

```
//edit my account endpoint
app.post("/account/edit", auth, (request, response) => {
    const filter = {email: request.user.userEmail}
    const {name, email} = request.body
    const update = {name:{name}, email:{email}}
    User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
        .then((result) => {
            response.send(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.status(404).send({
                message: "User not found",
                error,
            });
        })
    }
)
```

Both of these return 500 errors. What am I doing wrong?

Here is where I call the API, EditProfileForm.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();
const token = cookies.get("TOKEN");

function EditProfileForm() {

    const [ user, setUser ] = useState({name:"", email:""});

    const saveChanges = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = user.name;
        const email = user.email;
        const configuration = {
            method: "post",
            url: "https://MYURL/account/edit",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            data: {
                name,
                email,
            }
        };
        axios(configuration)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                error = new Error();
            })
    }

    // useEffect executes once the page loads 
    useEffect(() => {
        // set configuration for API call
        const configuration = {
            method: "get",
            url: "MYURL/account",
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
        };
        axios(configuration)
            .then((result) => {
                //assign the User to the in result to User we initialized
                setUser(result.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                error = new Error();
                window.location.href="/";
            });
    }, []);

    return(
    <div className="edit-account">
        <form className="edit-profile-form">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <p className="edit-form-tag">Name:</p>
                    <input 
                        className="edit-form-input" 
                        id="edit-name"
                        value={user.name || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, name: e.target.value})}
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p className="edit-form-tag">Email:</p>
                    <input 
                        className="edit-form-input" 
                        id="edit-email"
                        value={user.email || ''}
                        onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, email: e.target.value})}
                    />
                </li>
                <li>
                <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => saveChanges(e)}>Save Changes</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}

export default EditProfileForm;
```

Also if there are any ways I can improve my question, please let me know. I am still figuring out best practices, and trying to make each question clearer than the last.

Comment: Look at your server's error logs, they'll probably tell you why you're getting a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying below code can u check that email in User Schema is unique or not. If its unique and you're passing email that is already present in DB it will not modify the data.

```
app.post("/account/edit", auth, async (request, response) => {
    try{
        let user = await User.updateOne({email : request.user.userEmail}, {
            $set : {"name" : request.body.name,
                    "email" : request.body.email
                   }
            });
            response.status(200).json({
                success : true,
                data : "Updated Successfully"
            })
    }
    catch(error){
        response.status(404).send({
                message: "User not found",
                error,
        });
    }
)
```

Comment: email is unique. I have been logging into one of my test accounts that does not have a name and trying to edit profile to add a name. I did also try one that had a name already and tried to change it. both gave the same error

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I will have to change up the form to make this work. it currently autofills the form to current DB values, you can change name or email, then when you click save changes it submits everything, even fields that were not changed. I will try what you posted in just a moment

Comment: I got a CORS error, on all my API's now so i cant even sign in now. "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Oops, so I found a missing bracket. Now I just get a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I finally figured out how to check my server logs in heroku. Saw the error was while trying to read the request body. Did more googling. Finally figured out that I needed to add jsonParser to the post request for it to be able to read the request.body. It works now! I'll certainly never forget this again... haha

```
app.post("/account/edit", jsonParser, auth, (request, response) => {
    User.updateOne({email: request.user.userEmail}, {
            "name":request.body.name,
            "email": request.body.email
        }
    )
        .then((result) => {
            response.status(200).send({
                message: "User updated successfully",
                result,
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            response.status(404).send({
                message: "User not found",
                error,
            })
        });
    }
)
```